# How to open new form once process in command line is complete

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to figure this out for the best part of a day now and I cannot wrap my head around this issue.

I do not have much prior code knowledge but I try to research before I attempt to code anything. I have a basic understanding of how VB.net works but need some help with my code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim CopyFrom As String
Dim CopyTo As String
Dim RoboCopyVariables As String
Dim CopyS As String
Dim CopyE As String
Dim WaittimeTXT As String
Dim WaitTime As String
Dim RetryAttemptsTXT As String
Dim RetryAttempts As String
Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("CMD")

Private Sub RunBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunBTN.Click
    CopyFrom = CopyFromTXT.Text
    CopyTo = CopyToTXT.Text
    'All of the selections for if CopyS has been checked
    If CopySFoldersCB.Checked = True Then
        CopyS = " /s"
    ElseIf CopySFoldersCB.Checked = False Then
        CopyS = ""
    End If
    If CopyEFoldersCB.Checked = True Then
        CopyE = " /e"
    ElseIf CopyEFoldersCB.Checked = False Then
        CopyE = ""
    End If
    If WaitTimeCB.Checked = True Then
        WaittimeTXT = WaitTimeTXT1.Text
        WaitTime = " /w:" & WaittimeTXT
    ElseIf WaitTimeCB.Checked = False Then
        WaitTime = ""
    End If
    If RetryAttemptsCB.Checked = True Then
        RetryAttemptsTXT = RetryAttempts1.Text
        RetryAttempts = " /r:" & RetryAttemptsTXT
    ElseIf RetryAttemptsCB.Checked = False Then
        RetryAttempts = ""
    End If
    RoboCopyVariables = CopyS + CopyE + WaitTime + RetryAttempts
    'CommandTest.Text = "/k robocopy " + CopyFrom + " " + CopyTo + "" + RoboCopyVariables

    Process.Start("CMD", "/k robocopy " + CopyFrom + " " + CopyTo + "" + RoboCopyVariables)

    For Each p As Process In pProcess
        p.Kill()
    Next

    Form2.Show()
    Me.Hide()


End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelButton.Click
    Me.Close()
    Form2.Close
End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for all the help I recieve

Comment: You cannot find out it is complete when you use the /k option.  Use /c instead.  Or run it directly without using cmd.exe.  Use the Process.Exited event to detect completion, the Process.SynchronizingObject property to let it run on the UI thread.  Do *not* kill all cmd.exe processes, you have no idea if you started them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, since **RoboCopy** is a command-line interface application (things badly known as "external command" in Batch) then you should call it directly, because there is no need to call the Windows command-line just only to "host" another app.

Secondly, to solve the main problem that you are having, you can use the [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, this will block the current thread until the process has exited.

```
Dim p As New Process
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Robocopy.exe"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("""{0}"" ""{1}"" {2}", 
                                      CopyFrom, CopyTo, RoboCopyVariables)

p.Start()
p.WaitForExit(-1)
```

Another solution is to to enable the process to raise events then subscribe to the [`Process.Exited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event, this will result in a non-thread-blocking mechanism good for asynchronous scenarios.

```
Public Class yourClassName

    Friend WithEvents P As New Process

    ' Call "Test" method somewhere...
    Sub Test()

        Dim copyFrom As String = ...
        Dim copyTo As String = ...
        Dim roboCopyVariables As String = ...

        Me.P.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        Me.P.StartInfo.FileName = "Robocopy.exe"
        Me.P.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("""{0}"" ""{1}"" {2}", 
                                                 copyFrom, copyTo, roboCopyVariables)

        Me.P.Start()
        ' Can do any thing here while asynchronouslly we wait for the process to exit...

    End Sub

    Private Sub P_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles P.Exited

        ' Show the form here...
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

When using the code you have supplied I decided to go with the second solution.
Although I am currently recieving some errors.
Friend WithEvents P As New Process

This line in-particular.
I get the errors for 'Friend' and 'WithEvents'
the errors I am getting are '' is not valid on a local variable declaration

Comment: @DaMrZ `Friend` and/or `WithEvents` can be only declared outside method blocks, just declare the object outside the method. If you still preffer to declare the object inside the method block, then use `Dim` (alone) then use `AddHandler` statement to associate a handler to the `p.Exited` event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx .Please consider to mark the answer as accepted if solved the problem.

Comment: I declared it outside of the method but now I am getting the error 'Declaration Expected.' for every P

Also CopyFrom is giving that error aswell

Comment: Only the "P" object need to be declared outside, see the Edit I made to my answer to show an example of structure.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it and it is now working :)

Comment: I now have a new issue which is when Form2.Show() is executed the form goes into not responding and I get an error message from debugging which is ' An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll'

I cannot figure out why this is happening I think it has something to do with multi threads but I am not too sure Could you help please

Comment: Without entering in details, try this: `Form2.Invoke(Sub() Form2.show())` and `Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.Hide)`